# No descarga correctamente el archivo el navegador Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

Tengo un problema al descargar un archivo con `Internet Explorer` en cualquier versión. Mi problema consiste en que yo recibo un arreglo de bits desde mi controlador el cual lo recibo en un `JSON` y lo descargo desde `javascript`.

**Nota:** No tengo un archivo físico en el servidor, este archivo se obtiene desde un `storage` por medio de un `WebService`.

El código funciona bien en otros navegadores pero no en `Internet Explorer`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Portal/GetXML',
    data: $('#formDownload2' + id).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error == "") {
            //aquí empieza la descarga del archivo
            var arr = data.Archivo;
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
            var a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
            a.download = data.Nombre;
            // Append anchor to body.
            document.body.appendChild(a)
            a.click();
            // Remove anchor from body
            document.body.removeChild(a)
        } else {
            $.jGrowl("" + data.error, {
                header: "Error",
                //sticky: true,
                theme: "red"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Lo único que hace es descargar un archivo con un nombre largo y sin extensión. En otros equipos con `Internet Explorer` descarga un archivo con extensión: `.JSON`

**¿A qué se debe que me los descarga de esa manera? y ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?**

Comment: ¿Recibes JSON de un servicio llamado GetXML?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si recibo un `JSON` de esta forma o muy similar (no lo tengo a la mano) `{'data':[{'archivo':[{272},{23},{123}...]},{'nombre':'Factura del Fulano'}]}`, donde el archivo es un arreglo de bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es clásico de `Internet Explorer`, se debe a que dicho navegador desconoce qué hacer con contenido `application/json`

Lo que debemos especificar es el contenido al regresar `JSON` definimos:   `string Content Type: "text/html"`

En tu controlador que retorna `JSON`:

```
return Json(loQueRetorna, "text/html");
```

Te sugiero el `text/html` lo definas siempre y cuando el navegador sea IE.

Comment: desde el controlador envió el arreglo de bits del archivo, y desde `javascript` descargo el archivo pero el Explorer me descarga un archivo ya sea sin extensión o bien descarga un archivo con extensión `.json`, entonces si cambio a `.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'text/html' }));` debería descargarlo normalmente?

Comment: no tengo a la mano el código para hacer pruebas en cuanto tenga el equipo del trabajo lo implementare, solo espero que con lo que comentas también lo descargue `firefox`, `chrome` y `safari`

Comment: esperemos que así sea :D

Comment: No funciono con `text/html`, lo que hice fue cambiar el tipo de MIME a `application/xml` y lo descargo sin problema aunque no me gusta el nombre que le da el `Explorer` a comparación de los otros navegadores que le dan el nombre que yo sugiero, pero es lo de menos.

Comment: Sólo hay una explicación para es: Internet Explorer. Eso lo hiciste en el controlador cierto? //así queda para que futuros programadores encuentren solución en estos lares. Saludos hermano

Comment: lo hice en `window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/xml' }));` del `success` ya que del controlador solo recibo un arreglo de bits en un `json`